# Haskell: How to product a file like a list

Tags: haskell

I am a new one for studying Haskell, and I want to write a small phone book program. I put the contact list in a file called phone.txt
which like:

```
("xie","123")  
("bob","234")
```

And my program is :

```
import System.IO
main = do        
       handle <- openFile "phone.txt" ReadMode  
       contents <- hGetContents handle 
       name<-getLine       
       putStrLn $ [findNumber name contents]

findNumber x [] = "not found"
findNumber x ((y,z):ys) = if x==y then z else findNumber x ys
```

This program is for looking the number by input a name, why can not I compile it?
What's wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were nearly there... here's my solution (not optimized for performance):

```
import System.IO

main = do
       handle <- openFile "phone.txt" ReadMode
       contents <- hGetContents handle
       let phonebook = map readEntry $ lines contents
       name<-getLine
       putStrLn $ findNumber name phonebook
       where readEntry line = read line :: (String,String)

findNumber x [] = "not found"
findNumber x ((y,z):ys) = if x==y then z else findNumber x ys
```

Have fun further with Haskell :)

Comment: Thakn you very much. But I still have a question. Why I modify my code like yours, it says error, but when I just copy your code and paste, then it will pass the compile. I swear I type the right code! This kind of error really driving me crazy.

Comment: Hi Xie, please check your indentation - correct spacing is important in Haskell. And if this solved your question could you please accept it? (Green tick icon)

Answer (score 1):

`findNumber` has the following type:

```
findNumber :: Eq a => a -> [(a, [Char])] -> [Char]
```

However, your second argument in `findNumber name contents` has type `String`, not `[(a, [Char])`. You need to interpret the String you got from `hGetContents` correctly:

```
toDict :: String -> [(String, String)]
toDict = map read . lines
```

Afterwards you can search in `toDict contents`:

```
putStrLn . findNumber name $ toDict contents
```